# open file named with two digit year-Python

Tags: python

I'm opening a file named in the following format :

```
ex130626.log
exYYMMDD.log
```

following code wants 4-digit year. How to get the two digit year like 13?

```
today = datetime.date.today()
filename = 'ex{0}{1:02d}{2:02d}.log'.format(today.year, today.month, today.day)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just take the modulus of the year:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> today = datetime.date.today()
>>> filename = 'ex{:02}{:02}{:02}.log'.format(today.year%100, today.month, today.day)
>>> filename
'ex130625.log'
```

But an easier way is `strftime`:

```
>>> today.strftime('ex%y%m%d.log')
'ex130625.log'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `strftime`:

```
filename = 'ex' + today.strftime("%y%m%d") + '.log'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just take the last 2 like so :

```
year = str(today.year)[-2:]
filename = 'ex{0}{1:02d}{2:02d}.log'.format(year, today.month, today.day)
```